# How do I get latest date from table view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to fetch the latest date from a SQL Server 2008 R2 view I created but I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Expired User' to data type smallint

This is the query I used to create the view

```sql
SELECT
    dbo.Biostar.ClockinDate,
    dbo.Biostar.Staff_Number,
    dbo.Biostar.First_In_Time,
    dbo.Biostar.Last_Out_Time,
    R.status,
    RA.status2 AS status1,
    dbo.Biostar.Remarks,
    dbo.Biostar.Remarks2,
    dbo.Biostar.score,
    dbo.Biostar.score2
FROM dbo.Biostar
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Attendance_remark AS R ON dbo.Biostar.Remarks = R.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.Attendance_remark AS RA ON dbo.Biostar.Remarks2 = RA.ID
```

And this my query to get the latest date from the view

```
SELECT MAX([ClockinDate]) 
FROM [TimeAndAttendance].[dbo].[sys_attendance_latest]
```

Comment: There is an assumption in the query defined for the view that causes the error - go correct that query.

Comment: You need to **show us** the code used to create that view ...

Comment: I added the code I used to create thee view. Thanks @marc_s

Comment: Whitespace is free, you know. And you should learn how to use table aliases. Curious why you would want a `FULL JOIN` here but not relevant

Comment: `dbo.Biostar.Remarks = R.ID` Seems that this join (and the other) are the problem. You use a remarks column that is intended as a string of random text to act as an ID for your relationship. Your assumption is that this column only contains valid, non-formatted numbers and at least one row contains the value mentioned in the error. That value and any others (of which you should expect more) cannot be converted to int - the datatype of R.ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with the view. You join on Remarks = R.ID and Remarks2 = RA.ID. The error suggests that either Remarks or Remarks2 contains the value "Expired User" which it was unable to convert to an INT to join on ID. Confirm the data types for the join columns.